Difference between effect of a force and an impulse
I came through a saying that

"A regular force (force acting on the body throughout the consideration) or torque corresponding to that force will produce an acceleration/angular acceleration first and velocity/omega develops only after certain time, while an impulsive force/torque corresponding to it develops velocity/omega instantaneously and acceleration/angular acceleration develop after some time."

I am compelled to think things like how can motion start before developing velocity/omega only with acceleration/angular acceleration in the first case, etc.
Do I have to treat these things as a fact or there can be some logic behind it?

Quote from where? Link? Which page?

Same question as Qmechanic. Quotes out of context tend to be useless

What do you mean by "after some time"? Acceleration is the time derivative of velocity and that's it. There is no such thing as "before" or "after" involved here.

Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question with a straightforward answer. We do not need to know the source of the quote in order to explain why it is incorrect.

@gandalf61 This isn't even close to being clear, let alone "perfectly" clear.

@Qmechanic My teacher had said that, i did ask him, but he explained haphazardly. I was not quoting any text, had I been, would have explicitly mentioned

Re "Do I have to treat these things as a fact or there can be some logic behind it?"  See the math behind the Heaviside step function and the Dirac Delta Distribution.


A regular force ... will produce an acceleration/angular acceleration first and velocity/omega develops only after certain time ...

This is incorrect. As soon as the acceleration of an object becomes non-zero, its velocity starts to change at the same instant. The acceleration gives us the rate of change of velocity - so a small acceleration acting for a long time gives the same change in velocity as a large acceleration acting for a short time. But in both cases the change in velocity starts at the same instant that the acceleration becomes non-zero - there is no delay.

... an impulsive force ... develops velocity/omega instantaneously and acceleration/angular acceleration develop after some time ...

Also incorrect, for the same reasons as given above.
An "impulsive" force is simply the label that we give to a force that acts for a short time - there is no substantive difference between a "regular" force and an "impulsive" force.
If a force acts on an object (and it is the only force acting on the object) for a certain time then the change in momentum of the object is equal to the integral of the force with respect to time. We call this the impulse of the force. So a large force acting for a short time causes the same change in momentum as a smaller force acting for a longer time, because both forces have the same impulse. We call a force "impulsive" when it acts for a short time and when we are not concerned with the details of how the force might vary over this short time, but only with the impulse of the force.

In other words we neglect the acceleration associated with the impulsive force for that short amount of time? I actually am solving a problem where they consider velocity due to impulse but no acceleration

@AkshatSingh Yes, if we are not interested in how the force or the acceleration that it causes varies during the short time that the force is exerted, then we can just use the impulse of the force to find the change in momentum (and hence change in velocity) of the object to which it is applied.


Do I have to treat these things as a fact or there can be some logic
behind it?

If by "these things" you mean the quoted material, I find it difficult to see the logic behind the material as discussed below. It would be helpful if you could provide the source of the quoted material so it can be seen in fuller context. In any case, my comments:

"A regular force (force acting on the body throughout the
consideration) or torque corresponding to that force will produce an
acceleration/angular acceleration first and velocity/omega develops
only after certain time..."

I'm not sure what they mean by "develop", but if the body begins at rest then obviously the magnitude of the resulting translational or angular velocity will be a function of time, being zero at time $t=0$.

"...while an impulsive force/torque corresponding to it develops
velocity/omega instantaneously and acceleration/angular acceleration
develop after some time."

Impulse, or impulse of force, is defined as the product of the average force and the time it is exerted. It equals the rate of change in momentum of an object or, where the mass is constant,
$$Impulse = F_{ave}\Delta t=m\Delta v$$
from which
$$\Delta v=\frac{F_{ave}}{m}\Delta t$$
So once again, depending on what they mean be "develop", if the object begins at rest its initial velocity will be zero and its final velocity will depend on the elapsed time and the average force exerted on it over that time. So it's not clear to me exactly what your source is trying to say.
Assuming when they refer to "a regular force (force acting on a body throughout the consideration)" they mean a force of constant magnitude, then the difference between their "regular force" and an impulse of force is the value of the latter varies during the time it is exerted. This is typically the situation in the case of collisions.
The average force during a collision can be determined by the change in momentum that occurs if the time of the collision is known. A variation is the use of the work energy principle where the product of the average force and stopping distance equals the change in kinetic energy of an object, such as the change in kinetic energy that occurs over the stopping distance of a car when it collides with a non-movable object.
Hope this helps.

A force is a force. Sometimes forces act for a long time (gravity for instance acts all the time), and sometimes forces act for a very short time, like the contact forces between hard spheres colliding. In the latter case we sometimes call it "impulsive force", but the effect of a force is always the same: it causes acceleration, or on other words change in momentum.
To figure out how much the momentum changes, we integrate the force over the time it acts (or if the force is approximately constant we simply multiply the force and the time interval). This quantity is called impulse.

The main point of contention is that why will an impulse bring velocity first, followed by acceleration but a regular force will bring acceleration first followed by velocity

That is not true. If "Bringing velocity" means changing the velocity, then that's what acceleration is.
